# How do I get a CD Key for a family shared game?

Tags: steam

A friend gave me family access to his games, and several of them require the CD Key. How do I get a CD Key for a family shared game?

Comment: Which games are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 4):

If they are new games with third party, online authenticated, DRM like products from Ubisoft: You don't.

The key is tied to your friends account and those other DRM products don't allow library sharing so you're out of luck. You would have to log in on your friends account in that DRM and risk the account getting banned.

In older games which just have a CD key check with no online verification you'd probably have to ask your friend. They can see the CD key by selecting the game in their library and, under the heading Links on the right side, clicking on "CD key".